# create instance of a class using function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, object

I want to define a function that takes in name, type and list of parameters(of class) as input and creates an instance of class of given type and given name with specified parameters. and Save it in a dictionary with name as key Value How to do it?
I have tried using

```
return globals()['name']=globals()['type](globals("".join(list_of_parameter)))
```

but it didn't work I even tried to use `eval()`

instead of `globals()` but it doesn't work either.

(name and type are strings list_of_parameters is a list of strings where each string is a variable or object)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this using strings for the class name instead of passing the class itself? It can be done, but it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Actually I have to store the object created in a dictionary with name as keyValue that's why I need object of specified name.

Answer (score 0):

While there are more all-encompassing ways to do this, it can be very dangerous if you end up instantiating a class you weren't expecting to.

A simple way to accomplish this is to have a dictionary of all of the classes you will permit this code to instantiate, for example:

```
In [1]: class_dict = { "int" : int, "str" : str }

In [2]: args = [1]

In [3]: i = class_dict["int"](*args)

In [4]: i
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: args = ["test"]

In [6]: s = class_dict["str"](*args)

In [7]: s
Out[7]: 'test'
```

Comment: I want to have object of specified type with specified parameters

Comment: Please see edit, you can provide arguments using a list, or if the arguments are fixed, you can pass them directly

Answer (score 0):

What about using

`exec("...", globals(), locals())`

Note the globals() and locals().
"..." stands for class init in python syntax.

exec executes the code, the globals and locals is that the code executed in exec is not "catched" in the exec-namespace.

Comment: I don;t get it, Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the names of your variables (including classes) as data. If you need to be able to refer to a given value (e.g. a class) by a specific string, put it in a dictionary with the string as a key. This way you know exactly what your data can refer to.

So, try something like this:

```
def call_func_in_namespace(callable_name, arg_names, namespace):
    args = (namespace[name] for name in arg_names)
    return namespace[callable_name](*args)
```

You'd call it with something like:

```
namespace = {"int": int, "base": 3, "val": "212102"}

result = call_func_in_namespace("int", ("val", "base"), namespace)
```

There are lots of variations you could try, depending on what your actual use for this is. The callable and arguments could come from different namespaces, for instance. I'd just strongly encourage you not to use `globals()` as the namespace.